# How to use android xml UI code in React native?

Tags: android, xml, react-native, user-interface, bridge

I have several xml files written in android UI.
These codes are shown as a list in React Native, and when selected, the UI in xml must be displayed.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/canvas" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"/>
.....
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How should I handle the above situation?
Is there a way to use android UI code in React Native?